# kml overlay in phone browsers

Tags: android, iphone, maps, symbian, kml

I've recently had great success overlaying my kml files on just about every device out there with the exception of phones without a Google Maps app [GMM]

Put simply:
On any [most] Android devices, iPhones, desktops, laptops, netbooks & notebook computers, see or go to my test http://henrysinn.com/maps

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can set up the URL/link for another phone Browsers? I note http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://henrysinn.com/test/AldiSites.kml 'works' but is god-awful slow on iPhones, so-so on Android phones but is completely unusable on the vast numbers of Symbian phones that are still out there [globally]. Not sure re the various iterations of Blackberry or the upcoming WP7 we 'might' see more of..

Can it be done?

Henry Sinn
Melbourne
Australia

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Google Maps API to set up a basic map and then using the KMLLayer feature of the API to display your KML overlay: http://goo.gl/iExOp